# Bring two json objects into one using oracle sqlplus

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have the below query:

```
SELECT json_object('time' VALUE localtimestamp) || ' '||
json_object('db_schema' VALUE 'USER1') || ' '||
json_objectagg(JOB_STAT value count(ID) returning varchar2(32000))
FROM <TABLE> GROUP BY job_stat;
```

and the output is given as follows:

```
{"time":"2020-10-20T16:47:39.117075"} {"db_schema":"USER1"} {"SUBMIT":123,"RUN":456}
```

I actually want it like this:

```
{"time":"2020-10-20T16:47:39.117075","db_schema":"USER1", ["SUBMIT":123, "RUN":456]}
```

So that it's all in one object. Can you help change the query so that this can be achieved?

Comment: Please say which version of Oracle you're using. Later versions of Oracle have more capabilities, and that's certainly true with JSON, where Oracle has been adding features to every release since 12c.

Comment: `["SUBMIT":123, "RUN":456]` is invalid JSON. Did you mean to not have the `[]` brackets? Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Oracle version supports it, you can use `JSON_MERGEPATCH`:

```sql
SELECT JSON_MERGEPATCH(
         json_object(
           'time' VALUE localtimestamp,
           'db_schema' VALUE 'USER1'
         ),
         json_objectagg(
           JOB_STAT VALUE COUNT(id)
         )
         RETURNING CLOB
       ) AS json
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY job_stat;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, job_stat ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'SUBMIT' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 456
UNION ALL
SELECT LEVEL, 'RUN' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 123;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | JSON                                                                             |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | {"time":"2020-10-20T13:15:27.947079","db_schema":"USER1","SUBMIT":456,"RUN":123} |
> ```

Or, if you want an array, you can aggregate twice:

```sql
SELECT json_object(
         'time' VALUE localtimestamp,
         'db_schema' VALUE 'USER1',
         'job_stats' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG( json_job_stat )
       ) AS json
FROM   (
  SELECT JSON_OBJECT( JOB_STAT VALUE COUNT(id) ) AS json_job_stat
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY job_stat
)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | JSON                                                                                               |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | {"time":"2020-10-20T13:25:37.406742","db_schema":"USER1","job_stats":[{"SUBMIT":456},{"RUN":123}]} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=460bc625cadda093cf272c645c54eae1)*

Comment: Fantastic!! Absolutely love it. Thank you so much you rock.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
with fq as (select owner,table_name,count(0) cnt
from all_tab_columns group by owner,table_name)
select json_object('owner' value owner, 'Tables' value json_arrayagg(json_object(table_name value cnt)returning clob ) returning clob) json_val
from fq
group by owner
```

json_arrayagg returns an array in the json format. It takes an expr as the value, that's why I used json_object inside. This can probably be improved upon to get closer to what you want.
The output looks like this (in sqlcl):

```
{"owner":"XDB","Tables":[{"XDB$H_LINK":8},{"JSON$COLLECTION_METADATA_V":35},{"XD
B$ELEMENT":1},{"JSON$USER_CREDENTIALS":3},{"XDB$DXPTAB":11},{"XDB$DBFS_VIRTUAL_F
OLDER":2},{"X$PT46MP5MDR0M04NE0KWN0SK0K1LN":2},{"PATH_VIEW":4},{"DOCUMENT_LINKS"
:6},{"XDB$STATS":1},{"XDB$RESCONFIG":1},{"XDB$XTAB":11},{"APP_USERS_AND_ROLES":3
},{"X$NM46MP5MDR0M04NE0KWN0SK0K1LN":2},{"XDB$TTSET":4},{"XDB$SIMPLE_TYPE":1},{"X
DB$CHOICE_MODEL":1},{"XDB$GROUP_REF":1},{"XDB$NONCEKEY":1},{"XDB$CHECKOUTS":4},{
"APP_ROLE_MEMBERSHIP":2},{"XDB$NLOCKS":3},{"XDB$TSETMAP":3},{"XDB$IMPORT_TT_INFO
":5},{"XDB$ANYATTR":1},{"JSON$USER_ROLES":3},{"JSON$USERS":5},{"XDB$PATH_INDEX_P
ARAMS":4},{"XDB$ROOT_INFO":18},{"XDB$ATTRGROUP_REF":1},{"XDB$ALL_MODEL":1},{"XDB
$XIDX_IMP_T":5},{"JSON$COLLECTION_METADATA":8},{"XDB$REPOS":16},{"XDB$XTABNMSP":
6},{"XDB$IMPORT_PT_INFO":2},{"XDB$IMPORT_NM_INFO":2},{"XDB$COLUMN_INFO":4},{"XDB
$CDBPORTS":3},{"XDB$SCHEMA":1},{"XDB$ATTRIBUTE":1},{"XDB$RESOURCE":1},{"XDB$ACL"
:1},{"XDB$GROUP_DEF":1},{"XDB$MOUNTS":5},{"XDB$XIDX_PARAM_T":3},{"X$QN46MP5MDR0M
04NE0KWN0SK0K1LN":4},{"RESOURCE_VIEW":3},{"XDB$RCLIST_V":1},{"XDB$ATTRGROUP_DEF"
:1},{"XDB$CONFIG":1},{"XDB_INDEX_DDL_CACHE":11},{"XDB$IMPORT_QN_INFO":4},{"XDB$H
_INDEX":5},{"XDB$XDB_READY":1},{"JSON$USER_COLLECTION_METADATA":7},{"XDB$ROOT_IN
FO_V":18},{"XDB$COMPLEX_TYPE":1},{"XDB$ANY":1},{"XDB$SEQUENCE_MODEL":1},{"XDB$XT
ABCOLS":7},{"XDB$XIDX_PART_TAB":4},{"XDB$D_LINK":4}]}
```